# Access user info using access token for Office 365 oAuth

Tags: oauth-2.0

```
var clientId = 'xxxxxxx';
var replyUrl = 'http://localhost:55452/HTML/Dashboard.html';
var authServer = 'https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?';
var responseType = 'token';
var Office365Login = authServer + "response_type=" + responseType + "&" + "client_id=" + clientId + "&" + "resource=" + resource + "&" + "redirect_uri=" + replyUrl;
```

I am able to receive access token along with redirect url. Now using access token how i can access user information like Name, email ID? To which URL i need to make Ajax request and get information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through below link:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33525.an-introduction-to-microsoft-graph-api.aspx

Updated URL configurations:

```
var clientId = 'xxxxxxx';
var replyUrl = 'http://localhost:55452/HTML/Dashboard.html';
var authServer = 'https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?';
var responseType = 'token';
var resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
var Office365Login = authServer + "response_type=" + responseType + "&" + "client_id=" + clientId + "&" + "resource=" + resource + "&" + "redirect_uri=" + replyUrl;
```